# If statement - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can I add "Silver" and "Gold" in this line, my current code apply some functions on "Gold" plan only I wanna make it for both "Silver" and "Gold"

```
$subscription = rcp_get_subscription( get_current_user_id() );
if( $subscription == 'Gold' ) {
    // do something here
}
```

http://docs.restrictcontentpro.com/article/1653-rcpgetsubscription

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually want is an OR not an AND - a subscription can't be both silver and gold.

```
if( $subscription == 'Gold' ||  $subscription == 'Silver' ) {
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: Exactly "or" . Thank you.